# How to customize threshold PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision

I have trained ResNet50 for binary image classification.
I want to descrease FalseNegatives by reducing threshold value.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "threshold value" ? Do you get probabilities and only consider a prediction as good if the probability exceeds a threshold ?

Answer (score 1):

To decrease the number of false negatives (FN) i.e. increase the recall (since `recall = TP / (TP + FN)`) you should increase the positive weight (the weight of the occurrence of that class) above `1`. For example [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html?highlight=bcewithlogitsloss#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) allows you to provide the `pos_weight` option:

> `pos_weight > 1` increases the recall, `pos_weight < 1` increases the precision.
> For example, if a dataset contains *100* positive and *300* negative examples of a single class, then `pos_weight` for the class should be equal to `300/100 = 3`. The loss would act as if the dataset contains `3*100 = 300` positive examples.

As a side note, the explicit expression for the binary cross entropy with logits (where "*with logits*" should rather be understood as "*from logits*") is:

```
>>> z = torch.sigmoid(q)
>>> loss = -(w_p*p*torch.log(z) + (1-p)*torch.log(1-z))
```

Above `q` are the raw logit values while `w_p` is the weight of the positive instance.